# Buscar archivo en un directorio pero que no exista C#

Tags: c#, rutas, file

Tengo que testear que al buscar un archivo por nombre en un directorio este no exista y me lo indique por pantalla. Os enseño mi código, donde está el comentario de las interrogaciones es donde tengo el problema, lo demás funciona correctamente:

```
static void recorrerDirectoriosYCompararPorFicheros(string dir1, string dir2)
{
    System.IO.DirectoryInfo dirOrigenInfo = new DirectoryInfo(dir1);
    System.IO.DirectoryInfo dirDestinoInfo = new DirectoryInfo(dir2);

    System.IO.FileInfo[] fileDirOrigenNames = dirOrigenInfo.GetFiles("*.*");
    System.IO.FileInfo[] fileDirDestinoNames = dirDestinoInfo.GetFiles("*.*");

    for (int i = 0; i <= (fileDirOrigenNames.Length) - 1; i++)
    {
        System.IO.FileInfo file = fileDirOrigenNames[i];
        for (int j = 0; j <= (fileDirDestinoNames.Length) - 1; j++)
        {
            System.IO.FileInfo file2 = fileDirDestinoNames[j];
            if (file.Name.Equals(file2.Name))
            {
                mostrarResultadoComparacionPropiedades(file.FullName, file2.FullName);
            }
            else//????????????????????
            {
                Console.WriteLine("\nEl archivo {0} no existe en {1}", file.Name, dir2);

            }
        }

    }

}
```

Aquí os dejo el resultado, me indica comparación por comparación si existe o no, lo que quiero es que se recorra el directorio y me indique solo una vez si existe o no, el fichero que no existe es `c.txt`:
Fecha de Creación o última modificación NO son iguales
Los archivos C:\Projects\CarpetaOrigen\a.txt y C:\Projects\Carpe
taDestino\a.txt no son iguales por fecha de creación y por última modificación

> El archivo a.txt no existe en C:\Projects\CarpetaDestino
>
> El archivo a.txt no existe en C:\Projects\CarpetaDestino
>
> El archivo a.txt no existe en C:\Projects\CarpetaDestino
>
> El archivo c.txt no existe en C:\Projects\CarpetaDestino
>
> El archivo c.txt no existe en C:\Projects\CarpetaDestino
>
> Fecha de Creación y última modificación son iguales Los 
>   C:\Projects\CarpetaOrigen\c.txt y C:\Projects\CarpetaDestin o\c.txt
>   son iguales por fecha de creación y por última modificación
>
> El archivo c.txt no existe en C:\Projects\CarpetaDestino
>
> El archivo Configuration.ini no existe en C:\Projects\CarpetaDestino
>
> El archivo Configuration.ini no existe en C:\Projects\CarpetaDestino
>
> El archivo Configuration.ini no existe en C:\Projects\CarpetaDestino
>
> Fecha de Creación o última modificación NO son iguales Los archivos
>   C:\Projects\CarpetaOrigen\Configuration.ini y C:\Pr
>   ojects\CarpetaDestino\Configuration.ini no son iguales por fecha de
>   creación y p or última modificación

Answer (score 3, accepted):

En tu código estás cogiendo cada archivo del directorio origen y comparándolo con cada uno de los archivos existentes en el directorio destino. En cada comparación, si no coincide el nombre, concluyes que no existe el archivo (erróneamente porque que no coincida con el primer archivo no significa que no vaya a coincidir con otro) y sin embargo sigues buscando.

Lo que deberías hacer es buscar en todos los archivos destinos el nombre del archivo origen y, al final, concluir si se ha encontrado o no.

Para simplificar el código puedes utilizar LINQ en lugar de bucles anidados:

```
static void recorrerDirectoriosYCompararPorFicheros(string dir1, string dir2)
{
    System.IO.DirectoryInfo dirOrigenInfo = new DirectoryInfo(dir1);
    System.IO.DirectoryInfo dirDestinoInfo = new DirectoryInfo(dir2);

    System.IO.FileInfo[] fileDirOrigenNames = dirOrigenInfo.GetFiles("*.*");
    System.IO.FileInfo[] fileDirDestinoNames = dirDestinoInfo.GetFiles("*.*");

    foreach (var file in fileDirOrigenNames)
    {
        var file2 = fileDirDestinoNames.FirstOrDefault(f => f.Name == file.Name);
        if (file2 == null)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"\nEl archivo {file.Name} no existe en {dir2}");
        }
        else
        {
            mostrarResultadoComparacionPropiedades(file.FullName, file2.FullName);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: cierto, no sabía como resolverlo. Gracias por la ayuda! Para la siguiente lo tendré en cuenta

Answer (score 1):

Yo usaría Linq y `Contains` para comprobar que el nombre que estás procesando no existe en la colección de destino:

```
for (int i = 0; i <= (fileDirOrigenNames.Length) - 1; i++)
{
    System.IO.FileInfo file = fileDirOrigenNames[i];
    if (!fileDirDestinoNames.Select(x=>x.Name).ToList().Contains(file.Name))
    {
        Console.WriteLine("\nEl archivo {0} no existe en {1}", file.Name, dir2);
    }
    else
    {
        for (int j = 0; j <= (fileDirDestinoNames.Length) - 1; j++)
        {
            System.IO.FileInfo file2 = fileDirDestinoNames[j];
            if (file.Name.Equals(file2.Name))
            {
                  mostrarResultadoComparacionPropiedades(file.FullName, file2.FullName);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: mejora el resultado, pero me seguía pasando que fuese recorriendo e indicando que no existía por cada archivo que comparaba. Igualmente me ha servido, gracias!

Comment: Si,efectivamente mi código estaba mal, lo he editado para corregirlo. De todas maneras, la respuesta de @AsierVillanueva da una solución mucho mejor.